# How do I create a batch file that reads a file and writes a substring into another file?

Tags: parsing, batch-file, substring

I currently have an exported text file (`output.txt`) from a Clear-Case command that I need to parse.  It looks like this:

```
Comparing the following:
  R1.PROD.V1@\VOB_pvob
  R2.PROD.V1@\VOB_pvob
Differences:
>> M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME@@
>> M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME\file 2.txt@@
>> M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME\file 1.txt@@
>> M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME\file 3.txt@@
```

What I would like to do is use the findstr command to filter the strings that are contained between the "`>>` " and "`@@`" strings to get an output file that looks like this (with quotes if possible:

```
"M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME"
"M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME\file 2.txt"
"M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME\file 1.txt"
"M:\ACME_PROD\src\ACME\file 3.txt"
```

I am new to writing batch files and so I don't exactly know where to start.  I have managed to find code that can loop through the lines of a text file and separate code for the findstr command, but I get stuck trying to put it all together!

Best regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=> " %%a in ('"findstr /r [\w^>*] output.txt"') do (
set line=%%a
set line=!line:@=!
echo "!line!" >>new.txt
)
```

The filtered strings will be outputted into `new.txt`.

Comment: This is excellent!  How can I get it to only copy the lines starting with >> instead of all of the lines?

Comment: @Andrew Sorry, I didn't relise that was taking the other lines, I have updated my answer.